# bootstrap-select get the value and the text

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-select

I try to do a selections on companies to add to a group, and after that to do the connection in database. I'm kind of blocked on the "html" code. I work in Laravel

```
<select id="selectCmp" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple title="Select structures">
    @foreach($allCompanies as $company)
        <option value="{{$company->id}}"> {{$company->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<form action={{route('admin.group.affect')}} method="POST" target = "votar">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div id="cmpInputList">

    </div>
    </br>
    <button id="addGroupeBtn" class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">
        Add
    </button>
</form>
```

Ok, if try to inspect the element, I have something like:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick dropup">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
            data-id="selectCmp" title="Select structures" aria-expanded="true"><span
            class="filter-option pull-left"> Select structures</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span
            class="caret"></span></span></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" style="max-height: 560px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 142px;">
        <div class="bs-searchbox"><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" role="textbox"
                                         aria-label="Search"></div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false"
            style="max-height: 504px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 86px;">
            <li data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option"
                                           aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span
                    class="text"> A</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="1"><a tabindex="0" class="selected" data-tokens="null" role="option"
                                           aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true"><span
                    class="text"> B </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
            <li data-original-index="2"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option"
                                           aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span
                    class="text"> C </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="selectCmp" data-live-search="true" title="Select structures"
            class="selectpicker" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="1"> A</option>
        <option value="0">B</option>
        <option value="2"> C</option>

    </select>
</div>

<iframe name="votar" style="display: none;"></iframe>

<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/affectCmpToGroup" method="POST" target="votar">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="KSyRBJq6p6yJBPJnv0EOsC2sJwEe2SbzjxtLtuI5">
    <div id="cmpInputList"></div>
    <br>
    <button id="addGroupeBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
        Add
    </button>
</form>
```

So I have a `ul` with the `innerText` and mention about selected or not. My problem is how to give the `innerText` and the value from option (the id) to the form in order to pass that to controller and to database.

I hope it's clear... I'm kind of new in all this.

Comment: Found. Even if from the inspect is not clear, if I do $('#selectCmp').val() I get the ids of selected values

Answer (score 13):

For non 'multiple' select it is simply `$('#selectCmp').val()` and

`$('#selectCmp option:selected').text()`.

In this case the array of chosen options ids can be also gotten via `$('#selectCmp').val()`.

To get array of selected option names, it can be done like this:

```
$('#selectCmp').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
    var options = $('#selectCmp option:selected');
    var selected = [];

    $(options).each(function(){
        selected.push( $(this).text() ); 
        // or $(this).val() for 'id'
    });

    // write value to some field, etc
});
```

Though this code might not be neccessarily bound to 'changed.bs.select', depending on your app logic.